# How to implement app icon in Phonegap / Cordova according to the 2019 new icon specifications from Google?

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

Google recently gave in new icon design specifications for all new Android apps. All apps are required to follow this new specification.

Here's the link: https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications

**Question:**

**How do we implement this new set of specifications in our Phonegap/Cordova app?**

As it is currently done, all icons are put in `res` folder according to their `dpi` type like `xxxhdpi`,`hdpi`,`mdpi` etc.